# how to query mysql database with where clause using dynamic array

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to query mysql database with where clause as below.

Here popularTopicsNames is a dynamic array and its length and elements varies.

```
var scoreQuery=connection.query('SELECT * FROM LEADERBOARD WHERE SUBTOPIC IN ('+popularTopicsNames+')', function(err,result,fields){
if(err) throw err;
else{
    console.log(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just an array then you're trying to pass it as a string, which won't work.

Try

```
var scoreQuery = connection.query("SELECT * FROM LEADERBOARD WHERE SUBTOPIC IN ('" + popularTopicsNames.map(mysql.escape).join("','") + "')",
    function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're missing the beginning and end single quotes right inside the parenthesis. Without them you'll end up with invalid SQL for more than 1 item in the array. Example: SELECT * FROM LEADERBOARD WHERE SUBTOPIC IN (foo','bar)

Comment: Also, if the topic names are user submitted, then they should be properly escaped first to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I think you need something like `popularTopicsNames.map(mysql.escape).join("','")` instead.

Comment: @mscdex You're right, as the escape return value wraps it in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the issue in a more readable way.

```
var scoreQuery = connection.query(`SELECT * FROM LEADERBOARD WHERE SUBTOPIC IN (?)`, [popularTopicsNames],
(err, result, _fields) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```